# Rails Asset Pipeline with AngularJS: Any plugins to get rid of inline annotation injection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, dependency-injection, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails + AngularJS project that doesn't use the [inline annotation injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification) and using [gulp-ngcompile](https://github.com/ceymard/gulp-ngcompile) to compile my scripts. But now I would like to replace gulp with asset pipeline. Is there's any asset pipeline plugins act just like gulp-ngcompile?

There are too many scripts looks like the following and thus hard to covert them to inline annotation:

```
myApp.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $http) {...});

// inline annotation:
myApp.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {...}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions you might want to give them a try:

1. https://github.com/kikonen/ngannotate-rails

   ngannotate-rails uses https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate to deal with the inline annotations, so you can keep your code clean. However, somehow it doesn't work for me in the development mode, but it does work in production mode. (I'm not really sure why, but you may want to try it)
2. If you're using the default uglifier, you can turn off the name mangling as suggested by thoughtbot in http://robots.thoughtbot.com/avoid-angularjs-dependency-annotation-with-rails

   The caveat is that you loss the optimal minimized javascripts ... JavaScript will still be minified – whitespace stripped out and code nicely compacted – but the variable and parameter names will remain the same.

Comment: add `config.ng_annotate.process = true` to `development.rb` in order to activate in development mode. remember to clear cache (`bundle exec rake assets:clobber`) in order to rebuild.